# Problem with loading language_model_learner fastai

Tags: python, fast-ai

I have problem with fastai library. My code below:

```
import fastai
from fastai.text import *
import os
import pandas as pd
import fastai
from fastai import *
lab = df.columns[0]

data_lm = TextLMDataBunch.from_csv(r'/AWD', 'data.csv', label_cols = lab, text_cols = ['text'])

data_clas = TextClasDataBunch.from_csv(r'/AWD', 'data.csv', vocab = data_lm.train_ds.vocab, bs = 256,label_cols = lab, text_cols=['text'])
data_lm.save('data_lm_export.pkl')
data_clas.save('data_clas.pkl')

learn = language_model_learner(data_lm,AWD_LSTM,drop_mult = 0.3)

learn.lr_find()
learn.recorder.plot(skip_end=10)

learn.fit_one_cycle(10,1e-2,moms=(0.8,0.7))

learn.save('fit_head')
learn.load('fit_head')
```

My data is quite big, so each epoch in fit_one_cycle lasts about 6h. My resources enables me only to train model in SLURM JOB 70h, so my whole script will be cancelled. I wanted to divide my script into pieces and the first longest part has to learn and save fit_head. Everything was ok, and after that I wanted to load my model to train it again, but i got this error:

**RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for SequentialRNN:
size mismatch for 0.encoder.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([54376, 400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([54720, 400]).
**

I have checked similar problems on github/stack posts and I tried those solutions like this below, but i cannot find anything usefull.

```
data_clas.vocab.stoi = data_lm.vocab.stoi
data_clas.vocab.itos = data_lm.vocab.itos
```

Is there any possibility to load trained model without having this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `learner.save()` only the model weights are saved on your disk and not the model state dict which contains the model architecture information.

To train the model in a different session you must first define the model itself. Remember to use the same code to define your new model. Since your data is quite heavy as you mentioned you can use a very small subset (~16 records) of your data to create this new model and then do `learn.load(model_path)` and you should be able to resume training.

you can modify the training data with `learn.data.train_dl = new_dl`